# kubectl proxy unauthorized when accessing from another machine

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, kubectl

I have Kubernetes running on a VM on my dev box.  I want to view the Kubernetes dashboard from the VM host.  When I run the following command:

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts ^/.*
```

When I try to access the dashboard I get an unauthorized error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you run this on the VM or your computer?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The --accept-hosts access control is for checking of the *hostname*, so it won't start with a / (slash). You need to do:

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

(Make sure you shell escape the .* as it may match files in the current directory!)

More information at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_proxy/

Comment: I still get this error `Error: 'malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.244.1.2:8443/'`

Comment: That error message seems to suggest that on port 8443 the apiserver is using **https** and you are trying to connect via **http**. You can change the port/protocol in your [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) file.